# vue.config.js configureWebpack not used in unit tests (vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

In my vue config I have the following:

```
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, 'composition/react'),
      hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, 'composition'),
    },
  },
},
```

In my component I have the following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
```

This is so I can re use some of the Vue code in React projects. This works when running and building the project but not when testing. When unit testing I get the error: `Cannot find module 'react' from 'useCategories.js'`, the above import is from useCategories.

The following is in the jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest'
  }
}
```

If unit testing in vue is ignoring values from vue.config.js then how can I set the webpack path resolve values for testing. I would rather not repeat these values but if it's a JavaScript file I guess I can import it from the same file in different configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack isn't used in Jest, this would make module testing impractical, so Webpack config cannot affect anything.

As [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack) explains, it's necessary to provide module mapping in Jest config as well, e.g.:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^react$': '<rootDir>/composition/react',
  ...
```